# Setting up success callback in CakePHP with Js helper

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Here is the callback I want to set up with the Js helper, but I cannot find any information or examples regarding this.

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#EventProjectId').html(data.html); 
}
```

Here is the ajax call that I have for now:

```
    $this->Js->get('#EventCustomerId')->event('change',
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'events',
        'action'=>'getbycustomer'
        ), array(

        'update'=>'#EventProjectId',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression' => true,
        'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => true,
            'inline' => true
        ))
        )
    ))
    );
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->Js->request(array(
        'success' => "function(data) {
            $('#EventProjectId').html(data.html); 
         }",
        'controller'=>'events',
        'action'=>'getbycustomer'
        ), array(

        'update'=>'#EventProjectId',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression' => true,
        'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => true,
            'inline' => true
        ))
        )
    ))
    );
```